# Can I find out the GameCenter user name that's actively logged in?

Tags: xcode, ios4, game-center

I'd like my iphone app to pre-populate some fields once a user has logged into gamecenter. Specifically, the username!

I have full logging in working - as well as a leaderboard and acheivements all working -  I just can't seem to find out how to access the users name property anywhere.

Any advice / help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kolya
PS - This is my first question. Please be nice :-)

Here is the code I'm trying:

```
if ([GameCenterManager isGameCenterAvailable]) {

    self.gameCenterManager = [[[GameCenterManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.gameCenterManager setDelegate:self];
    [self.gameCenterManager authenticateLocalUser];

    NSLog(@"User alias: %@",[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer]alias]);
```

But the NSLog outputs "User alias: (null)"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the local player is the subclass of GKPlayer, you could use this:

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer]alias]
```

Oh.. you have not authenticate the user... It is the first step..

```
 GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
[localPlayer authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
     if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated)
     {
         // Perform additional tasks for the authenticated player.
     }
 }];
```

I think you can just replace the 3 lines of codes with the code above.. Should work..

Comment: I've updated the question with some code - including your answer xuanweng - but still not working.